# How can I get past World 3-10?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

I'm having trouble getting past the last portion of World 3-10 in *Scribblenauts Remix*. I've managed to get the man and his dog past the first 2 areas with a heavy bridge, and a long bridge, but the last portion with a gap over fire has me stumped. The hint refers to  fire-resistant. I've tried various fire resistant materials: steel, asbestos, etc. I've put out the fire with rain and even created a "fire-resistant bridge" and laid it across, but the man and dog just sit and wait. I'm sort of at a loss after various attempts. I'm sure the answer is obvious, but it's not coming to me. Any ideas of how to pass would be appreciated.

Here they are doing nothing even though they *should* be able to cross:
[image: Here they are doing nothing even though they should be able to cross]

Comment: Have you tried "fire proof" instead of "fire resistant"?  You've also got to put the fire out with rain, but from the screenshot it looks like you've done this already.

Comment: @agent86 your suggestion did work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just completed level 3-10 using "heavy bridge", "long bridge" and "stone bridge". I didn't need to put out the fire for the man and dog to walk across.

Answer (score 1):

Across the first pit type heavy bridge. Across the second pit type long bridge. Across the final pit type wet bridge. that's how I got past that level.

Answer (score 0):

I did stone bridge at the end, and only the dog got across, but I got the star before the blind man popped.

Answer (score 0):

I beat this level by doing "heavy bridge", "long bridge", and "fire proof bridge". I tried "fire-resistant bridge", but it didnt work, so I did "fire proof bridge", which did.